# Using the `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>` trick in Rust, but across multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

It's a common trick to annotate your functions with returning `Result<X, Box<dyn Error>>` to allow them to return any error at all. However, you can't return this from a thread without the error itself implementing `Send`. For example this code:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1
use std::error::Error;

fn main(){
    ["1", "2", "three"]
        .into_par_iter()
        .try_for_each(|i| -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error>> {
            let inner = i.parse::<usize>()?;
            Ok(inner)
        }
    );
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn std::error::Error` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8ec31b715714d2c05e22388a8fdd0a8))

---

On the other hand, if you try to specify that the error must implement `Send`, the `?` operator no longer works:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1
use std::error::Error;

fn main(){
    ["1", "2", "three"]
        .into_par_iter()
        .try_for_each(|i| -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error + Send>> {
            let inner = i.parse::<usize>()?;
            Ok(inner)
        }
    );
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>`
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6adc1a6523c5fd5a3b978acebd228fa))

How can I continue to use the `Box<dyn Error>` shortcut, but only for errors that can be sent, allowing it to work across threads?

Comment: In my experience, this "common trick" always comes back to bite you in such ways, and you're better off defining your own error type. The `thiserror` crate is my personal favourite to do this with a tolerable amount of boilerplate, but there are several alternatives.

Comment: I agree with Thomas. How often do you actually *need* a function to be able to return every type of error in an indiscriminate way, and how often is it just a crutch so you don't have to think about what sorts of things can go wrong? All you're doing is adding C++-style unchecked exceptions to Rust and making it completely impossible for anyone to do anything other than log the errors and panic.

Comment: You're probably right, and I could be using the `anyhow` create here. But this is the "built-in" way to handle dynamic errors. The problem it's solving is having a closure that could raise multiple different error types, when I can't be bothered unifying them using my own error types.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo There _are_ situations when you just want to report failure to the user - e.g. when you accept a callback that can fail in ways you cannot anticipate. That need is covered by the `anyhow` crate, whose titular type is basically a wrapper around `Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>`, and whose popularity shows that there is ample need for this. (Its author is David Tolnay who also wrote `thiserror` and `serde`, among others.) Unlike with C++ exceptions, propagation is explicit, involves returning `Result`, and typically uses the `?` operator, so nothing happens behind your back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implemention in `std` you are looking for is [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CE%3E-1):

```
impl<'a, E: Error + Send + Sync + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'a>
```

Change your closure's return type to `Result<usize, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>`, fix the unrelated type error, and it will compile.

Comment: Great solution, particularly because it uses a trait implementation already in `std`, and the docs explain it in detail. For others' future reference, here's a playground using this solution with my original example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c745d56e7b055a6eb39f693ddc910f1

Comment: If this is the solution you are looking for, please mark it as accepted so the question is closed.

Comment: Although it seems that all your own `Result<X, Box<dyn Error>>` functions that you call and use `?` on within the `Result<X, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>` function must also be modified to have the same signature.

Comment: Please leave me slightly more than 14 minutes to explore the pros and cons of the solution next time, thanks.

Comment: You can `try_for_each(...).map_err(|e| e as Box<dyn Error>)` to weaken the type, which is possible because you are no longer using threads outside of `try_for_each`. The error type will then be `Box<dyn Error>`, which should be compatible with everything else.

Comment: Consider also adding `+ 'static` to be able to transport the error between (non-scoped) threads, and to be able to convert it to `Anyhow`.